# What files are used for classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I have some classes in Eclipse which cannot be resolved to a type. I know that classes can be in .class, .jar, .par, .zip files. Are there any other file types that I have to look for? Or is there anything eclipse how I could make Eclipse recognize the classes?

In my general understanding, once I have found these files and added them to the classpath, the Eclipse should be able to recognize them.

Comment: Answer Bowie was meant to be a comment. Can't delete on phone. I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean java classes? They should have a .java extension.

Answer (score 2):

Actually my colleague gave me an answer:

If the class cannot be found or resolved to a type within Eclipse, this is only the problem with build path. And to the build path, the files should be added of type as I have said: class, jar, par, zip; no other suffix is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, so please excuse me if I am. Type resolution errors are often due to incorrect imports or misspellings. Ill give an example:

```
public class Foo extends Component{
//If you forgot to import java.awt.*; You would receive the error 
 "Component cannot be resolved to a type"
}
```

Also if you misspelled an extension you would get the same error.When you create a class in eclipse you need to create a new file for that class.

You should also post your code so we know exactly what you're talking about. I don't think your error has anything to do with the classpath. :)

Comment: See my answer. I did not work with java standard library, so actually it was the case that some classes were not in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Class path entry could be jar, zip or directory ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html))

set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2...

> Class paths to the .jar, .zip or .class files. Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on what you are setting the class path to:
> For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file.
> For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.
> For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name).
> Multiple path entries are separated by semi-colons. With the set command, it's important to omit spaces from around the equals sign (=).

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

> Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or .jar files) nor * are ignored.